# different code for different OS/screen

Tags: html, css

I have [a website](http://www.eurobytes.nl/) which i am trying to perfect, and what i want is something like this

```
if screen=1920x900 set size="100%"
if screen=1280x600 set size="50%"
if os="windows" set font="100%"
if os="osx" set font="50%"
if os="linux" set font="25%"
```

```
...width="{size}"
font-family="{font}"
```

note the above codes are just examples!

I want to be able to view my website, exactly in a brower in windows with screensize XXXX
as in the other browser´s/os's screensize's?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: use media query into css for screen size

Comment: @user1581900 You didn't get the question?

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is no question... I can see that he tries to perfect a website and he wants to be able to set different properties for various resolutions and OS, but I don't see a "?" anywhere in the OP..

Comment: He wants to target many screen sizes. Accordingly, he needs the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Screen Sizes, you can use **`@media` queries**.

#### Example:

```
@media screen
and (min-width: 600px)
and (max-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    background: #333;
  }
}

@media screen
and (min-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

Know more here:

- [WebDesignerWall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)
- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
- [CSS Media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)
- [CSS3 Previews » Media Queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/)

---

For targeting different versions of IE, you can use **conditional comments**.

#### Example:

```
<p class="accent">
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
</p>
```

---

Detecting OS is **not** a good idea. But to detect them, there are a lot of **plugins**.

- [jQuery browser and OS detection plugin](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/)
- [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Answer (score 2):

Hi now used to `CSS Media queries`

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

more info see the link below .

http://cssmediaqueries.com/

http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use jQuery to detect the browser size & OS version.

You can use the: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/ Plugin.

Then using If/Selects/Switches etc you can use different CSS depending on the browser/os/size etc.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to do? for setting css rules for different screen sizes look at CSS media queries (eg: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ ).

You can find define more filters like OS and things via PHP (eg: http://www.danielkassner.com/2010/06/11/get-user-operating-system-with-php )